# How would I be able to connect a local SQL database to the internet/ be internet-accessible?

Tags: sql-server, localhost, server

You may think this is a stupid question -- I'm not a computer science major by any means --- but say I want to play around with SQL Server Express (free edition).

Once I install it on my local machine, how would I be able to play around with it using remote/ web-based programs?

Like, as far as I know, I usually have to enter login/ hostname/ IP credentials to connect to a web-based SQL database. For a local machine, how exactly would this work? How would I "host myself" and connect my local machine to the internet (mostly just the database) -- I guess is the question here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Assuming that you want to experiment and learn the server hosting.

If your machine is already connected to the Internet, then find out the public internet IP address of your machine, by typing 'find my ip' in your browser google.com page.

### Option 1

1) If you want to access your machine from some other machine, then based on O/S of your local machine, enable the remote access and adjust firewall settings.

2) Use the IP address/Local user credentials to login to the machine and now you can access anything on that machine as If you logged in locally.

### Option 2

1) Use the IP address, Port and Credentials of the Database to access it from a different machine using the third party tool like Toad, squirrel etc...

2) Same IP, Port and Credentials can be used by any applications to update your database.

but you need to adjust your firewall and remote access settings before you do that.

Comment: Much appreciated. Is one of the options more conservative from a security standpoint? Just curious. Certainly gave me a lot to look into.

Comment: Option 2 is much better if you want to restrict the access only to your DB. In Option 1 user can access anything on your machine including DB. so it depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you would have to port forward the port you want to connect with (this depends on your router, I recommend checking for your router manual online). Then, when you connect from the Internet, replace "localhost" with your external ip (found using [WhatsMyIP](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) or similar on your local machine).